# understanding asyncio already running forever loop and pending tasks

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm having problems  understanding how to pend a new task to an already running event loop.

This code:

```
import asyncio
import logging

@asyncio.coroutine
def blocking(cmd):
    while True:
        logging.info("in blocking coroutine")
        yield from asyncio.sleep(0.01)
        print("ping")

def main():
    logging.info("in main funciton")
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    logging.info("new loop created")
    logging.info("loop running forever")
    loop.run_forever()
    asyncio.async(blocking("ls"))

logging.basicConfig(level = logging.INFO)
main()
```

Changing `run_forever()` to `run_until_complete(asyncio.async(blocking("ls"))` works fine. But I'm really confused - why I can't pend a task on the already running loop?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that the call to `loop.run_forever()` blocks; it starts the event loop, and won't return until you explicitly stop the loop - hence the **`forever`** part of `run_forever`. Your program never explicitly stops the event loop, so your `asyncio.async(blocking("ls"))` call is never reached.

Using `asyncio.async` to add a new task to an already running loop is fine, you just need to make sure the function is actually called from inside a coroutine or callback inside the event loop. Here are some examples:

Schedule `blocking` to run as soon as the event loop starts:

```
def main():
    logging.info("in main funciton")
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    logging.info("new loop created")
    logging.info("loop running forever")
    asyncio.async(blocking("ls"))
    loop.run_forever()
```

Schedule `blocking` from a callback executed by the event loop:

```
def start_blocking():
    asyncio.async(blocking("ls"))

def main():
    logging.info("in main funciton")
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    logging.info("new loop created")
    logging.info("loop running forever")
    loop.call_soon(start_blocking)  # Calls start_blocking once the event loop starts
    loop.run_forever()
```