# ASYNCIO: [ERROR] Task was destroyed but it is pending

Tags: python, async-await, runtime-error, python-asyncio, event-loop

```
async def run_check(shell_command):
    p = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(shell_command,
                    stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
    fut = p.communicate()
    try:
        pcap_run = await asyncio.wait_for(fut, timeout=5)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        p.kill()
        await p.communicate()

def get_coros(pcap_list):
    for pcap_loc in pcap_list:
        for pcap_check in get_pcap_executables():
            tmp_coro = (run_check('{args}'
            .format(e=sys.executable, args=args)))
            if tmp_coro != False:
                coros.append(tmp_coro)
     return coros

async def main():
    pcap_list_gen = print_dir_cointent()
    for pcap_list in pcap_list_gen:
        p_coros = get_coros(pcap_list)
        for f in asyncio.as_completed(p_coros):
            res = await f

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

**pcap_list_gen** is a generator of PCAP lists which contain multile lists.
I get *[OS: Error: To many open file]* if I pass all pcaps in a single list, so decided to group them into list of smaller size and process one at a time.

Each **pcap_list** is a list of multiple PCAPS.
I want the next iteration of the loop to only start once the first iteration is finished.

```
for pcap_list in pcap_list_gen:
    p_coros = get_coros(pcap_list)
        for f in asyncio.as_completed(p_coros):
            res = await f
```

As per my knowledge: The first loop is getting executed properly asa the iteration goes to next loop it throws error.

**Traceback:**

```
Exception ignored in: <generator object BaseSubprocessTransport._connect_pipes at 0x7f7b7c165830>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_subprocess.py", line 188, in _connect_pipes
    waiter.set_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 349, in set_exception
    self._schedule_callbacks()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 242, in _schedule_callbacks
    self._loop.call_soon(callback, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 497, in call_soon
    handle = self._call_soon(callback, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 506, in _call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 334, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
[ERROR]  Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<BaseSubprocessTransport._connect_pipes() done, defined at /usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_subprocess.py:156> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task._wakeup()]>>
```

**More logs**

```
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <bound method BaseSubprocessTransport.__del__ of <_UnixSubprocessTransport closed pid=70435 running stdin=<_UnixWritePipeTransport closing fd=12 open>>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_subprocess.py", line 126, in __del__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_subprocess.py", line 101, in close
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 568, in close
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 560, in write_eof
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 497, in call_soon
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 506, in _call_soon
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 334, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
[ERROR]  Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<ClassificationCheck.run_check() done, defined at ./regression.py:159> exception=RuntimeError('cannot reuse already awaited coroutine',)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
RuntimeError: cannot reuse already awaited coroutine
```

**O/P of _p_coros_  after for loop iteration in main() as**

```
P_COROS(1st iteration):  [<coroutine object ClassificationCheck.run_check at 0x7f746d984ca8>, <coroutine object ClassificationCheck.run_check at 0x7f746d984db0>, <coroutine object ClassificationCheck.run_check at 0x7f746d984f68>, <coroutine object ClassificationCheck.run_check at 0x7f746d984fc0>]
awating in block 'finally'
awating in block 'finally'
awating in block 'finally'
awating in block 'finally'
P_COROS(2nd iteration):  [<coroutine object ClassificationCheck.run_check at 0x7f746d984ca8>, <coroutine object ClassificationCheck.run_check at 0x7f746d984db0>, <coroutine object ClassificationCheck.run_check at 0x7f746d984f68>, <coroutine object ClassificationCheck.run_check at 0x7f746d984fc0>, <coroutine object ClassificationCheck.run_check at 0x7f746d943048>, <coroutine object ClassificationCheck.run_check at 0x7f746d9430f8>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./regression.py", line 325, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(ClassCheck.main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 387, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "./regression.py", line 201, in main
    res = await f
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 492, in _wait_for_one
    return f.result()  # May raise f.exception().
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
RuntimeError: cannot reuse already awaited coroutine
Exception ignored in: <bound method BaseEventLoop.__del__ of <_UnixSelectorEventLoop running=False closed=True debug=False>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 431, in __del__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 58, in close
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 139, in remove_signal_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/signal.py", line 47, in signal
TypeError: signal handler must be signal.SIG_IGN, signal.SIG_DFL, or a callable object
Exception ignored in: <bound method BaseSubprocessTransport.__del__ of <_UnixSubprocessTransport closed pid=89531 running stdin=<_UnixWritePipeTransport closing fd=8 open>>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_subprocess.py", line 126, in __del__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_subprocess.py", line 101, in close
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 568, in close
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 560, in write_eof
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 497, in call_soon
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 506, in _call_soon
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 334, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Comment: Relevant [understanding-asyncio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30558040/understanding-asyncio-already-running-forever-loop-and-pending-tasks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning says that at the moment you call `loop.close()` something related to process still running. I guess you should [wait()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#asyncio.asyncio.subprocess.Process.wait) for it's termination (read also note at the link). Try this:

```
try:
    pcap_run = await asyncio.wait_for(fut, timeout=5)
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    p.terminate()
finally:
    await p.wait()
```

**Upd:**

Oh, you probably used global `coros` variable:

```
def get_coros(pcap_list):
    coros = []  # <--------------- create new list to fill
    for pcap_loc in pcap_list:
        for pcap_check in get_pcap_executables():
            tmp_coro = (run_check('{args}'
            .format(e=sys.executable, args=args)))
            if tmp_coro != False:
                coros.append(tmp_coro)
     return coros
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error (_RuntimeError: cannot reuse already awaited coroutine_), see my original posts I have added more logs. Also tried p.communicate() got same traceback/

Comment: @NabaChinde I updated code snippet in answer, can you test if it'll work?

Comment: Getting the same issue. I don't think the issues here are related to _TimeOut_ as I am not using the data which will cause _TimeOut_. I think it is because of the 1st for loop in main. Please check my update logs for _p_coros_ in _main()_ under this **O/P of _p_coros_ after for loop iteration in main() as**

Comment: the reason I am confident that the issue happens with the 2nd iteration of for loops because when I use a limited number of pcap files such that the for loop just iterate one time over the _pcap_list_gen_. i:e when **len(pcap_list_gen) == 1**, it does not fail.

Comment: @NabaChinde, I updated answer. I guess we close to solution :)

Comment: Ahh. Spent more than a day on that.  But yeah got to learn a lot. Anyways that worked, Thanks. :)